# How to know from which position two vectors begin to be distinct?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

Suppose I have two huge vectors not necessarily of the same length say

```
 v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9, 10}
 v2 = {1,2,3,4,a,5,6,7,9, 10,11, 13}
```

I would like to know the first line where they depart one of the other.

And what to do if the format of the data is of the following type 2000-01-03

Here are two such list

```
  v1 =      {"2016-07-18","2016-07-19","2016-07-20","2016-07-21","2016-07-22","2016-07-23","2016-07-24","2016-07-25", "2016-07-26"}

  v2 = {"2016-07-18","2016-07-19","2016-07-20","2016-07-21","2016-07-22","2016-07-24","2016-07-25", "2016-07-26","2016-07-27","2016-07-28","2016-07-29"}
```

Comment: Please give an explicit example of list(s) containing the sort of data you speak of.

Comment: What should be the output, if `v2 = v1`? If `v2 = Append[v1, 1]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `Flatten[]`:

```
With[{pos = Position[(Length[{##}] == 2 && SameQ[##]) & @@@
                     Flatten[{v1, v2}, {2}], False]}, 
     If[pos =!= {}, pos[[1, 1]], pos]]
   5
```

(Thanks to Michael for noting the weakness of the previous version.)

Comment: Well, the OP doesn't care to clarify the question, so I'll try you: "What should be the output, if `v2 = v1`? If `v2 = Append[v1, 1]`?"  This method gives an error.

Comment: Yes, I did not account for that case. Let me modify this...

Answer (score 7):

```
l = Max[Length /@ {v1, v2}];
FirstPosition[PadRight[v1, l] - PadRight[v2, l], x_ /; x != 0]
```

Comment: Quantum_Oli, thanks for the quick answer. I have the out Missing["NotFound"] and I realise that the data were of the format 2016-07-18 because they are date

Answer (score 7):

Using `LengthWhile` or `While`:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4]
f1 = Function[{x, y}, 1 + LengthWhile[Range@Length@x, x[[#]] == y[[#]] &]];
f2 = 1 + LengthWhile[Subtract @@ PadRight[{##}], # == 0 &] &;
f3 = 1 + LengthWhile[Transpose@PadRight[{##}], SameQ @@ # &] &;
f4 = Module[{n = 1}, While[#[[n]] == #2[[n]], n++]; n] &;
```

Examples:

```
v1 = {"2016-07-18", "2016-07-19", "2016-07-20", "2016-07-21", 
  "2016-07-22", "2016-07-23", "2016-07-24", "2016-07-25", "2016-07-26"};
v2 = {"2016-07-18", "2016-07-19", "2016-07-20", "2016-07-21",  "2016-07-22", "2016-07-24", 
     "2016-07-25", "2016-07-26", "2016-07-27", "2016-07-28", "2016-07-29"};

#[v1, v2] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}
```

> {6, 6, 6, 6}

```
#[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, a, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13}]&/@{f1, f2, f3, f4}
```

> {5, 5, 5, 5}